# Android PACT demo application

Tags: java, android, testing, consumer, pact

I want to use [PACT](https://docs.pact.io/) testing tool in my application. I studied the pact workshop for `android`([link](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-android)) & `jvm`([link](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-jvm)) both. I gone through all the steps of this two workshops. I read implementation documents on PACT website. But still I am facing understanding issue of this PACT. I tried [pact android demo](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-android) . But it is not working & this demo application is too old. I have following questions :

- How can I do configure for my application?
- How can I establish connection between consumer & provider?
- How it works means the flow of application?

For understanding above question I need simple android demo. So that it will act like my consumer party & other demo server act like my provider. If I can have one demo application then I am able to debug the android application step by step & will help to understand the flow of application & pact testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question - are you asking about how Pact works in general?

> How can I do configure for my application?

You'll need to share your application for any advice/guidance on this.

> How can I establish connection between consumer & provider?

Your actual consumer and provider never communicate in a Pact test, the sequence of this is described in detail at https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/how_pact_works.

Your consumer only ever talks to the Pact mock service, and your Provider is verified by Pact.

Pact is designed to avoid *integrated* tests.

> How it works means the flow of application?

I'm not sure I follow this I'm afraid.

Comment: Another advantage is that your test does not require the full android environment that you get from running on a phone or in an emulator. 
You can test the service classes directly in a JVM.